# The Best of Stack Exchange Book

Tags: discussion, publishing

**Update**:
In response to the positive feedback progress is now being made towards producing the first ever physics SE book.  If you would like to see your own high quality answer in this book, please nominate your answer below and if there is sufficient interest I will include a section in the book with your requests.

If you are nominating your answer, please ensure both the question and answer doesn't include any images or references that may be copyright and please let me know of your nomination by **01/03/2017**.

If anyone is interested in reviewing the book prior to publishing please let me know.

---

As you may be aware, Quora has created a physical book compiling some of the top contributions from a variety of topics.

[image]

I'm wondering if there would be any interest in publishing a similar hard-copy book compiling the top posts from Physics.SE or perhaps even have the top posts from a variety of different SE sites in the one book.

What do you guys think?  Would anyone be interested in having such a book and do you think it should be for Physics only or include a variety of topics (e.g. include all science topics)?

Once we've determined the level of interest we can investigate the costs of publishing and if it is feasible.

Comment: This could also be asked on the main meta.

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code perhaps, but I'd rather start with our smaller community here first.  If it is a success then we can potentially ask on the main.

Comment: Related on mother meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273911/263383

Comment: On one hand I like the idea but on the other hand I don't think it will be worth the effort to publish the book without the help of the company (SE). Also, I'm not sure if the PSE community will be willing to fund the endeavour . It seems like a high input low output situation to me.

Comment: @anonymous I will be personally funding the endeavour and already have an affordable publisher.  I just now need to ascertain the level of interest in the book.

Comment: Related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/9189/2451

Comment: For me, interest depends significantly on what questions are in it.

Comment: I think it should be just physics. But I also think there's a whole rack of issues in producing a book. Which questions do you pick? Which answers do you pick? What if they've got lots up upvotes but they're flat-out wrong? What if a poster asks for a cut? What if it doesn't sell? A lot of the younger generation just don't read books. They don't like paying for things, especially things they can download for free. Good luck to anybody who wants to give it a shot. IMHO they will need it.

Comment: @JohnDuffield all posts on SE are CC-by-SA, so do not see how one would have a leg to stand on in asking for a cut.

Comment: @JohnDuffield The What-If XCKD book sold very well. I think most (all?) of the content in that book is online.

Comment: @Tim : noted. I do think XKCD is a bit special though. Love that [relativistic baseball](https://what-if.xkcd.com/1/)!

Comment: Its could be an interesting idea, especially if its packaged correctly and offered to the right audience. A lot can be made for the rapidly growing online  interest of the  wanna be physicist. A world where Google and the mutual interest of millions participate from around the world. Both layman and pro asking from different points of view. I feel quite confidant that sites like these are the breeding ground for the next paradigm shift. What's interesting about these important questions is the number of answers and how different they are but more interesting is how much we really don't know.

Comment: If you're looking for submissions, I can give a few of my posts that answer fun or interesting questions in a fun/easy to understand way

Comment: @Bill Alsept : it would be nice if you were right about sites like these being the breeding ground for the next paradigm shift. I see PSE as an "explain it to your grandmother" thing as it happens. _If you cannot explain it to your grandmother you do not understand it yourself_. Hence I've collected together all my own answers and I'm using them to drive something called _the physics detective_. I was originally thinking of a book, but now I intend it to be a free website. Something like Matt Strassler's blog, but with a "chapter" on the photon, on pair production, on the electron, etc.

Comment: @JohnDuffield I agree with the explaining to the grandmother part. This site is very useful in that way. But I'm talking about all the answers that are not correct or are the best answers we have right now. Those type are getting passed around in very interesting ways. For instance you mentioned the photon and we all know how many opinions there are on that subject.

Comment: @Bill Alsept : it's a tricky one. All the upvotes in the world won't make a wrong answer right, or make up for a lack of scientific evidence. And vice-versa. IMHO an issue for stack exchange is  _science is not a democracy_, and I don't think there's any solution to that. Such is life. Meanwhile, it's good to talk.

Comment: @JohnDuffield that's right we talk and talk until one little thing shifts our Way of reasoning and the floodgates of accumulated data change everything. It's happened before.

Comment: @JohnDuffield four post above you mention photon pair production. Not to change the subject here but maybe in chat would it be possible to answer a few questions? I am confused with many of the correlation experiments because there are so many different set ups. Could you explain how photon pairs would be setup and measured? Distances, frequencies, polarization? Maybe then from there I could be more specific. Thanks

Comment: @Jim I have selected the questions already now however you raise a good suggestion.  I'm happy to allocate some answers (e.g. 10) request their high quality answer to appear in the book.  Do you have a particular answer you would like to see in the book, and preferably one where the question and answer don't contain references/images that potentially couldn't be included due to copyright.  Thanks

Comment: @Kenshin I have more than one. In no particular order, here are my favourite (or at least, my most recently reviewed favourite. I'm not going to go through all 300 answers I have): http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/195550/23473, http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/142884/23473, http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/64935/23473, http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/146170/23473, http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/133943/23473 I've got plenty more I'd have suggested too, but at some point I have to draw the line between honest suggestions and pure self-promotion.

Comment: @Kenshin Only if you think they'd be good for the book. I wouldn't want you to put something in merely because I asked. But if you're at a point where you want some filler questions about a certain topic, let me know. I'll suggest some I might have on the topic or, if I don't have good ones, I'll suggest posts from others that I know are great for the topic.

Comment: um...1/3/2017 had already passed when you asked this question =) please update the date.

Comment: @heather in Australia we go day/month/year, I'll update later for clarity :)

Comment: *"In response to the positive feedback..."* I'm curious. Link?

Comment: @DanielSank hahaha did you not notice the 11 upvotes on the post?  But even if just one person is interested in the book at least I have made someone happy.

Comment: I am glad to know such thing is also going on, because one day I was worried if all the questions are disappeared :)  I will love to review the book. I know I am late (I was in hibernation)

Comment: @L.K. Are you aware that all user-provided content on SE is regularly data-dumped to archive.org? Fears of this site's content disappearing are unfounded.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty can we be sure that site you have linked is always going to be up and running?  Is the site backed by the US government or something?

Comment: @Kenshin that's the Internet Archive, and if it goes down then Internet preservation has much bigger problems than just SE. Thinking that a single printed book (in a single limited edition with low numbers) can best their efforts is laughably simplistic; they are run by professionals with several decades of experience in Internet preservation. This project can offer several things, but increasing the Q&A corpus' long-term archivability is not one of them.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty indeed it was not my argument that this book should be a back up in case SE goes down.  I do however think one should always be aware that no private enterprise is immune to failure, including archive.org

Comment: It's also telling that you think "backed by the US government" is a silver bullet of stability, particularly since the IA just felt compelled to duplicate its database in Canada because they felt that the US political climate was not stable enough for long-term preservation efforts. In other words: leave it to the pros. Producing a worthwhile book will already provide you with an oversized serving of challenges.

Answer (score 1):

If I missed this in the comments, I apologise, but could you trial it on say,  the Kindle platform and see what the response is? I don't know Amazon's terms and conditions, and perhaps you have investigated this already. Best of luck with it anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I trust the tastes of the community generally, so I would like to nominate the most upvoted answers from the most [upvoted questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes), starting with [Cooling Cup of Coffee with Spoon](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5265/cooling-a-cup-of-coffee-with-help-of-a-spoon/5510#5510)

But then it seems to make the whole point of the book pointless if anyone can access what's already conveniently here.

Comment: Thanks @John, many of the top voted questions/answers will appear in the book however I should note that it is not the only indicator of quality.  Other indicators of quality have also been considered such as the number of down-votes, post-length, the number of votes on both the question and answer being published and more.  The book will also include questions from a variety of physics topics.

Comment: Honestly, the linked question is not actually that good a question and the answers are only so-so (and mostly contradictory to each other). The only reason it is so heavily voted is because Randall Munroe drew people to it in his What If blog.

Comment: @KyleKanos which goes to show how tastes differ, because I love the linked question. It's a great example of the interplay between experimentalists and theorists, with the correct answer being the experiment since it always trumps theory.

Comment: @JohnMcVirgo: Except the "experiment" was done exactly *once* without much control of the apparatus (notice the discrepancy of the initial temperature?). There is also *no* analysis of the "experiment", just the display of the single run. That's Mythbusters-level science there (i.e., not at all science).

Answer (score -4):

actually if u r really interested in giving out a really quality book how about trying like this
for one question we can find so many different answers in stack exchange site and also in google we can get some info
along with that we have many questions which relate very closely to one questions in addition to be having many answers and moreover many links regarding the related stuff are available 
from those links we can get some info 
so how about putting all this info together?
i know it takes a lot paper work and time and all
but what i think is if u want to go for something,  it would be always better to go for the best
so what do u think?