# Is this guy really allowed to sell our stuff like this?

Tags: discussion

I was distressed to find that someone called George Duckett appears to be (trying to) cash-in on stack exchange by selling things [like this](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=sIhRDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&hl=en#v=onepage&q&f=false).

I understand the terms of the license we publish our work under, but what I see here does not contain proper attributions (and links) to where the material came from or who produced it. There is a copyright page at the back which may or may not spell out the creative commons license, but since I can't see it, then it may as well not exist. In other "books", such as the one lifted from Astronomy SE, there is no mention of the creative commons license on this page.

I left a review pointing out that all this material is freely available and searchable already. The book adds no value and is at the very least morally questionable.

Comment: Related: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10581/2451

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to be able to read the whole book to check if it conforms to the CC BY-SA license, as Google Books provides the ability to search the book's full text.

Since there is no occurrence of "BY-SA", "ShareAlike", "Creative Commons", or "CC" (except for a couple of physics abbreviations) anywhere in the book, it seems pretty likely (although I'm not a lawyer and this isn't legal advice) that the book doesn't conform to the ShareAlike element of the CC BY-SA license.

If you're the author of any questions or answers copied in the book then this may entitle you to [file a DMCA report](https://support.google.com/legal/contact/lr_dmca?product=books) with Google.

Whether you do or not, it is worth taking comfort in the fact that while it's very easy to put up these kinds of copies (including ones that are more conformant with the license than this one) it seems unlikely it is fooling or profiting from many people at all. They are extremely low cost attempts to collect extremely low value ill-gotten gains. It amounts to very little more than a rather ugly kind of noise in the wastelands of the internet.

Comment: The [*"Contact"* link](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) (on the bottom of every Stack Exchange page, including this very page) has the specific reason ***"Stack Exchange content is being reproduced without attribution"*** (under *"What can we help you with?"*). More important, action is actually taken by Stack Exchange for these.